# How do I validate alphabetical characters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm beginning what will be a DNA translator. I have it set up to take the text from the DNA text box, make it all lower case. I know that much is working. However, the function made to validate that it is all alphabetical characters isn't working. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. The ultimate output won't be a "document.write()", thats just temporary to see if its working. The code is below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>DNA Translator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <form>
                <label for="dna">DNA:</label>
                <input type="text" name="dna" placeholder="DNA">
                <label for="mrna">mRNA:</label>
                <input type="text" name="mrna" placeholder="mRNA">
                <label for="trna">tRNA:</label>
                <input type="text" name="trna" placeholder="tRNA">
                <label for="aminoAcids">Amino Acids:</label>
                <input type="text" name="aminoAcids" placeholder="Amino Acids">
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button id="button_translate" type="button">Tanslate</button>
                    <button id="button_clear" type="button">Clear</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button_translate').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#button_translate').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#button_translate').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#button_translate').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
    });
    $('#button_clear').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#button_clear').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    });
    $('#button_clear').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#button_clear').fadeTo('fast', 0.7);
    });
    $('#button_translate').click(function() {
        var dna = $('input[name=dna]').val();
        var dna = dna.toLowerCase();
        function allLetters(text) {  
            var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;  
            if(text.value.match(letters)) {  
                document.write("That is a DNA sequence.");
            }
            else
            {  
                document.write("Not a real DNA sequence.");
            }  
        }

        allLetters(dna);
    });
});
```

CSS (if it matters):

```
#wrapper {
    margin-top: 10%;
}

label {
    width:100px;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", Myriad, "Liberation Sans", "Nimbus Sans L", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica;
    text-align:right;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#button_translate {
    float:left;
    opacity:0.7;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#293FE3;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
    /*display:block;*/
    margin:15px auto;
}

#button_clear {
    float:right;
    opacity:0.7;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#293FE3;
    font-family:arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:2px;
    /*display:block;*/
    margin:15px auto;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width:390px;
    height:20px;
    padding:4px 6px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
    color:#555;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    float:left;
    font-size:14px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius:4px; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -webkit-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -moz-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    -o-transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s;
    transition:border linear .2s, box-shadow linear .2s
}

form {
    width:524px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.buttons {
    text-align:center;
    float:right; 
    width:404px
}

#dna {
}

#mrna {
}

#trna {
}

#aminoacids {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text` is already your value which you want to match, so change:

```
if(text.value.match(letters)) {
..
```

to

```
if(text.match(letters)) {
...
```

Comment: That was indeed the issue. Thank you for the help. In 8 minutes, this will be marked as my "accepted answer".

Comment: Does function definition location matter? Is there a coding standard of its placement? ex. before the $(document).ready()? Also, where can I find a list of javascript functions such as .toLowerCase and other built in functions? I can't pull it all out of my brain yet, and it would be cool to have a repository of possibilities.

Comment: you can place the function before (document).ready() as well, for javascript reference you can check this:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype#Methods